# Django: Certain users get random 404 error

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I'm facing a strange issue that I can't handle on my own.

In normal cases when users click on a link, then they are directed to a page where they can edit their hook baits (objects). However, certain users get 404 errors, but I don't know why because the page is rendered for most users.

html where the link is

```
        <div class="row justify-content-center mx-2" >
            <div class="col-12 p-0">
                <ul class="list-group text-center custom-borders m-2 p-0">
                    {% if own_hookbaits.count == 0 %}
                    <a href="{% url 'user_profile:hookbaits' request.user.fisherman.fisherman_id %}" class="list-group-item" >No hook baits yet</a>        
                    {% else %}
                        {% for hookbait in own_hookbaits %}    
                        <a href="{% url 'user_profile:hookbaits' request.user.fisherman.fisherman_id %}" class="list-group-item">{{ hookbait.name }}</a>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>
```

views.py

```
class HookBaitUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = HookBait
    template_name = "user_profile/hookbaits.html"
    form_class = HookBaitForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = HookBaitFormset(queryset=HookBait.objects.filter(fisherman=self.request.user.fisherman))
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = HookBaitFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(formset)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(formset)

    def form_valid(self, formset):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            instance.fisherman = self.request.user.fisherman
            instance.save()
        return super().form_valid(formset)

    def form_invalid(self, formset):
        return HttpResponse("Invalid")

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('user_profile:profile', args=(self.kwargs['pk'],))
```

urls.py

```
app_name = "user_profile"
urlpatterns = [
    path("profile/<int:pk>/", views.ProfileView.as_view(), name="profile"),
    path("profile/<int:pk>/hookbaits/", views.HookBaitUpdateView.as_view(), name="hookbaits"),
]
```

rendered html

```
<div class="row justify-content-center m-0">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 p-0">
        <div class="row mx-3 my-3 justify-content-center text-center">
            <div class="card p-2 custom-borders">
                <div class="card-body p-2">
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <table class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                            {{ formset.management_form }}
                            {% for form in formset %}
                            <tr class="formset_row">
                                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                <td class="pb-2">
                                    {% if form.instance.pk %}{{ form.DELETE }}{% endif %}
                                    
                                    {% if forloop.first %}
                                    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                        {{ hidden }}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    {% endif %}
        
                                    {{ field.errors }}
                                    {{ field }}
                                </td>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </table>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-50 mt-1" style="background-color: #00754B;" value="Mentés">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions what the solution would be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there are some possibilities

1. the wrong link clicked like if your trying access this URL profile/25/hookbaits/
   and in the data index there is no  HookBait with the id of 25
2. in HookBaitUpdateView you are trying to get queryset=HookBait.objects.filter(fisherman=self.request.user.fisherman)
   maybe there is no hookbait associate with user.fisherman
   404 page mostly served when you call get_object_or_404(HookBait, pk=25)
   and update view may call this method

Comment: The update view renders a page where the user can see his own hook baits. The page is also rendered without any problem when there is no any hook bait yet.